# HTML5 Mobile App that accesses Java library?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I am working on HTML5 mobile app, that needs a Java library to be complete.  So I want to know exactly how to invoke java method from within javascript? The HTML5 will be wrapped in a WebView or something in Android app.  I need to know exactly how to invoke the java library from within HTML5.  Please be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out PhoneGap? It lets you build Android apps in HTML5 using a WebView and also lets you create Plugins written in Java and Objective-C.

PhoneGap
http://www.phonegap.com/

Examples:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

Comment: The implication are slim to none. I have a few apps using Phonegap on both stores without problems.